# Cloudsearch Request Exceed 10,000 Limit

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

When I search a query that has more than 10,000 matches I get the following error:

```
{u'message': u'Request depth (10100) exceeded, limit=10000', u'__type': u'#SearchException', u'error': {u'rid': u'zpXDxukp4bEFCiGqeQ==', u'message': u'[*Deprecated*: Use the outer message field] Request depth (10100) exceeded, limit=10000'}}
```

When I search for more narrowed down keywords and queries with less results, everything works fine and no error is returned.

I guess I have to limit the search somehow, but I'm unable to figure out how. My search function looks like this:

```
def execute_query_string(self, query_string):
    amazon_query = self.search_connection.build_query(q=query_string, start=0, size=100)

    json_search_results = []
    for json_blog in self.search_connection.get_all_hits(amazon_query):
        json_search_results.append(json_blog)

    results = []
    for json_blog in json_search_results:
        results.append(json_blog['fields']) 

    return results
```

And it's being called like this:

```
results = searcher.execute_query_string(request.GET.get('q', ''))[:100]
```

As you can see, I've tried to limit the results with the `start` and `size` attributes of `build_query()`. I still get the error though.

I must have missunderstood how to avoid getting more than 10,000 matches on a search result. Can someone tell me how to do it?

All I can find on this topic is [Amazon's Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/limits.html) where it says that you can only request 10,000 results. It does not say how to limit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `get_all_hits`, which gets ALL results for your query. That is why your `size` param is being ignored.

From the docs:

> get_all_hits(query) Get a generator to iterate over all search results
>
> Transparently handles the results paging from Cloudsearch search
>   results so even if you have many thousands of results you can iterate
>   over all results in a reasonably efficient manner.

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudsearch2.html#boto.cloudsearch2.search.SearchConnection.get_all_hits

You should be calling `search` instead -- http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudsearch2.html#boto.cloudsearch2.search.SearchConnection.search

Comment: Your second link is the same as the first one.

Comment: Updated the link. @MarcusLind did that solve your problem? Would appreciate your accepting the answer if so.